# Redirect Safari To Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to redirect user's of my mobile webapp to use Chrome rather than Safari. I tried using the following:

```
<script>
javascript:location.href="googlechrome"+location.href.substring(4);
</script>
```

However this constantly opens tabs in Chrome in a loop. Do you know how I can successfully do this?

Cheers,
Dara

Comment: What did you expect then? You're setting the href every time the page loads, that'll create an infinite loop for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the reason is pretty obvious; Chrome is instructed to open Chrome too. You just want a userAgent conditional.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("CriOS") == -1) {
  location.href="googlechrome"+location.href.substring(4);
}
```

I would go on my standard rant about user agent checking being bad, but I trust what you're saying about this being a private webapp. Since iOS doesn't let you change your default browser, I guess this is a fair workaround.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I'm trying to get a workaround due to iOS forcing you to use Safari. Unfortunately that script still causes a loop :(

Comment: @DaraG Sorry; I thought that Chrome was the signature string in iOS safari. I've just edited my post. Try it now (I don't have an iPhone to test, so it's on you)

Comment: This works lovely now. Thank you so so much! :) I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

This will cause the page to open every time the webpage is loaded, regardless if you are in Safari or Chrome. This is also very poor User Experience to just forward the user to another browser without their input.

It would be better to have some way for the user to open your site in Chrome and also to have an explanation why it is needed.

There are other schemes for `https` and callbacks: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/ios/links#uri_schemes

```
<p>This webapp is best viewed in Google Chrome</p>
<button type="button" onclick="openInChrome()">Open in Chrome</button>
<script>
    var openInChrome = function() {
        if (/^((?!Chrome).)*(Safari)+.*$/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            var protocol = location.href.substring(0,location.href.indexOf(':'));
            var url = location.href.substring(location.href.indexOf(':'));

            if (protocol === "http") {
                location.href = "googlechrome" + url;
            }
            else {
                location.href = "googlechromes" + url;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Edit:**

Added a check to verify they are in Safari.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified more, it's a private webapp and all users want it in Chrome and not Safari. Hence why I tried to set it up automatically.